# compute an integration

Tags: r

Here is my `integrand()`

```
 integrand<-function(x,vecC)
  {
   as.numeric((2/(b-a))*vecC%*%as.matrix(cos((x-hat.a)
 *(seq(0,N-1,length=N)*pi/(b-a)))))
  }
```

it can produce the value. For example, for

```
 a<-1
 b<-10
 vecC<-t(as.matrix(rnorm(80)))
 hat.a<--1.2
 N<-80
```

I get

```
 > integrand(1.4,vecC)
 [1] -0.3635195
```

but I met problem when I run the following code for integration

```
 > integrate(function(x){integrand(x,vecC)},upper = 3.4,lower = 1)$value
```

and the error message is

> Error in integrate(function(x) { : 
>       evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In (x - hat.a) * (seq(0, N - 1, length = N) * pi/(b - a)) :
>       longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the help page for `integrate` you will see that the function passed to `integrate` should return a vector.

So the solution to your error is to use `Vectorize` like this
Define your function separately as

```
 f <- function(x){integrand(x,vecC)}
```

Now define a vectorized version of this function like so

```
 fv <- Vectorize(f,"x")
```

and then

```
integrate(fv,upper = 3.4,lower = 1)$value
```

will give you a result.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! @Bhas